# lua http socket timeout

Tags: sockets, lua, luasocket

The LuaSocket HTTP module documentation says that a timeout can be set on a HTTP connection:

*The following constants can be set to control the default behavior of the HTTP module:*

PORT: default port used for connections;
PROXY: default proxy used for connections;
TIMEOUT: sets the timeout for all I/O operations;
USERAGENT: default user agent reported to server.
http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.htm

How do I set these constants in a lua script?

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it, so this question would be complete.

Comment: I tried but I have to wait 8 hours after the time of the first post before I can answer to my own question. I will do it this evening (CET).

Comment: That restriction should be gone now that you have over 10 rep points.

Comment: Nope. I still have thet same notice: New users can't answer their own question for 8 hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this to set a timeout for one request instead of the entire HTTP module:

```
local socket = require "socket"
local http = require "socket.http"
response = http.request{url=URL, create=function()
  local req_sock = socket.tcp()
  req_sock:settimeout(5)
  return req_sock
end}
```

---

Note that the default behavior of `:settimeout`, as well as global settings like `http.TIMEOUT`, sets a time limit *for any individual operation within the request* - in other words, it's how long the operation may go *without any activity* before timing out. If you wish to set an *overall upper bound* on an operation - a time that the overall request can't exceed, *regardless of activity* - you should pass a mode argument of `'t'` as the second parameter to `:settimeout`, like so:

```
local socket = require "socket"
local http = require "socket.http"
response = http.request{url=URL, create=function()
  local req_sock = socket.tcp()
  -- note the second parameter here
  req_sock:settimeout(5, 't')
  return req_sock
end}
```

As an example to illustrate the distinction between the two modes, imagine that, after making your request, the server responded with a chunk of the response once a second, taking seven seconds overall to complete. With `req_sock:settimeout(5, 'b')` (or just `req_sock:settimeout(5)`) setting a 5-second *block* timeout, this request would proceed just fine, as none of the *underlying I/O operations* took longer than five seconds: however, with `req_sock:settimeout(5, 't')` setting a five-second *total* timeout, the request would *fail* after five seconds.

Of course, it may make sense to set restrictions for *both* of these durations, having both a short *inactivity* timeout as well as a longer *overall* timeout. As such, [per the documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#settimeout), you can make two separate calls to specify *both*:

```
local socket = require "socket"
local http = require "socket.http"
response = http.request{url=URL, create=function()
  local req_sock = socket.tcp()
  req_sock:settimeout(5, 'b')
  req_sock:settimeout(30, 't')
  return req_sock
end}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. With the solution I found (posted below now), do I really change the timeout for all new HTTP sockets? If that is the case, I could reset its value to the default 60 seconds after the connection succeeded. Can you explain on your snippet, especially the `create = function()` part?

Comment: I just made some test and, indeed, when I change the timeout with `mysocket.TIMEOUT` it keeps that value for all new HTTP sockets created afterwards unless you change it again. With your suggestion don't you create two sockets? One http and one tcp?

Comment: @ripat The `create` parameter of the request specifies the function to *create* the TCP socket it uses to *perform* the HTTP request ([the HTTP Application layer going over the TCP Transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_model)). If you don't specify a create function, http.request will use a plain call to `tcp()` by default (see [the manual](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html)).

Comment: Oh, I see. Although setting the default value for the entire module for the duration of the script is usually not a problem, your solution offers better control on the HTTP socket. Thanks Stuart.

Comment: Line 2 `require "socket.tcp"` and Line 4 `local socket = tcp()` are **invalid**. Line 2 should be deleted and Line 4 should be `local socket = socket.tcp()`.

Comment: I got better results with req_sock:settimeout(2,'t'). The 't' is a mode that specifies that the timeout... well, idk. But it works

Comment: FYI, stack overflow (in my case) hid the last two comments (which are important). Can you change the line to req_sock:settimeout(5,'t') which will set the total timeout. The default 'block' timeout is not intuitive and doesn't behave the same as the similar "http.TIMEOUT=5" cases mentioned throughout answers to the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell [from the documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html), the "block" timeout mode *does* behave the same way as `http.TIMEOUT` - both control the timeout time *for each I/O operation*. I've added an explanation about timeout modes to the answer, but I'm sticking to the default in the initial section describing the alternative to `http.TIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 15):

It was easier than I thought. simply

```
local mysocket = require("socket.http")
mysocket.TIMEOUT = 5
```

Comment: does this have 'side effects', changing http socket configurations outside of the file that does the require ? (i.e. code on the same program but on another file that does its own require for http.socket)

Comment: @josinalvo: Yes, all files within a program share the same instances of their common modules under `package.loaded`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6021774/34799) for a way to do this without side effects.